# How to prevent a user from changing the selected row in an EditorGrid

Tags: gxt

Is there a way that I can prevent a user from changing the selected row? I was looking for something like a selectedRowChanging event that would either prevent or allow user from selecting a new row.

Comment: What kind of component does contain this rows? CheckBox, Grid or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda depends on how you have things set up...

I have a Grid to which I've added a CheckColumnConfig and RowEditor It's really a window into some DataBase tables.  The user can modify any column 'except' the key columns. The user may also Add a new row.  I defined 2 ColumConfigs.  The EditColumnConfig has the various fileds disabled (i.e. if (column = keyColumn) {textField.disabled(); } the AddColumnConfig has all columns enabled.

Now if the user clicks the checkBox on a row and clicks an 'Add' button I reconfigure the grid with the addColumnModel : rowDataGrid.reconfigure(listStore, addStateColumnModel); When the user clicks the RowEditor 'Save' button I erconfigure the grid back : rowDataGrid.reconfigure(listStore, editStateColumnModel);

I 'spose you could define an uneditable ColumnConfig and swap it in and out.  (or... catch the RowEditor 'BeforeEdit' event and disable to row).

That's an idea anyway...  hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.addListener(Events.BeforeEdit, new Listener<GridEvent<MyModel>>(){

    @Override
        public void handleEvent(GridEvent<MyModel> be) {
            //This retrieves the model being edited.
            MyModel model = be.getModel();
            if (I do not want to edit this model){
               be.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }           
});
```